# Работа с Python Imaging Library (Pillow)

Tags: pillow

Необходимо чтобы скрипт брал фотографию, и проводил по всей фотографии горизонтальные полосы чёрного цвета, шириной в 1 px, с интервалом между полосами так же в 1 px. Вот пример из фотошопа на белом фоне: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно сделать при помощи Python 3.x и PIL?

Желательно чтобы была легкая коррекция, зависящая от фона. На скриншоте видно, что цвет не чисто чёрный выбран в этом месте:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вероятно этого можно добиться если придать полосам немного прозрачности.

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь методом .getpixel() из модуля Image

from PIL import Image

Дальше - вопрос алгоритма, который бежит по пикселям и какие-то превращает в черный, какие-то в белый.

Это ответ на ваш вопрос.

Одновременно с этим, я очень хочу ответить: "Никак, используйте OpenCV" - и это ближе к удобству, просто загружаешь матрицу картинки и вперед

Comment: «from PIL import Image» и невнятное упоминание getpixel не являются ответом на вопрос. Кроме того, в Pillow есть методы для рисования линий, зачем getpixel какой-то